# jQuery: checkbox does not lose focus (blur) [IE]

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, focus, blur

I have a script, that lets a table row move to the top after clicking on a checkbox.

(*See my question here:* [jQuery: move table row to first position and then back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699081/jquery-move-table-row-to-first-position-and-then-back))

Now I have the problem, that after clicking on a checkbox and then on another the not checked checkbox does not blur and after clicking some more checkboxes multiple checkboxes have focus.

**example:**

- click on A
- then click on C
- in most cases A now has focus even it is not checked

**code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gguNM/2/

*Please note, that I have this problem in internet explorer, not e.g. in FireFox.*

What can I do to prevent multiple checkboxes (or the wrong cb) are focused?

I've already tried something like that:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () { setTimeout($(":checkbox").blur(), 100); });
```

but it does not change anything.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here? I'm having issues with blur not seeming to be called on checkbox clicking in Chrome...