# filter blur on checkbox element?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to filter blur on every element except the sidebar upon checking a checkbox. For some reason the other tabs i've checked wont work for me. When the navbar is checked I want everything except the navbar to be blurred and when unchecked not blurred. Why isn't this working?

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
      <input id="sidebar-input" type="checkbox" class="sidebar__input" />
      <label for="sidebar-input" class="sidebar__label"></label>
      <div class="sidebar__container">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">Skills</a>

        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">Resume</a>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">Github</a>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar__link">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.397);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 100;

 &__input:checked:not(.sidebar) {
    filter: blur(10px);
  }

}
```

Comment: If you like jQuery, this fiddle should help http://jsfiddle.net/carl_marie/fjq721zb/

Comment: if nobody else has an answer i suppose i'll go with this jquery answer, i do feel like this answer is a bit overkill though. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717135/jquery-checkbox-does-not-lose-focus-blur-ie

Comment: Your code only shows a sidebar? Are you able to create a working Snippet that demonstrates what you have so far? I don't see that the JSFiddle example does any blurring at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a website, with #sidebar and inside it #sidebar-input and you wish to blur everything expect #sidebar when #sidebar-input is checked - there is no way with css to add any styling to elements that are before checkbox or any parent, you can go only forward in DOM od deeper.

With code provided you might be able to blur everything inside #sidebar expect checkbox with something like this:

```
#sidebar-input{
    &:checked{
        &+label {
            filter: blur(10px);

            &+.sidebar__container{
                filter: blur(10px);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or remove blur if elements where blurred at the start. To blur everything expect #sidebar you need to use JS or jQuery, e.g.

```
$('#sidebar-input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $("body").addClass("blur")
        /*blur everything expect #sidebar in css*/
    }
    else{
        $("body").removeClass("blur")
    }
});
```